# Mystery Program in Startup Apps in Windows

Tags: windows

I was checking the apps that start automatically on Windows 11 by typing in `Startup Apps` and I found out there is a mystery `Program` that is set to start automatically:

[image]

Right clicking doesn't bring up any context menu.

How can I find out what this `Program` is?

Comment: I'd start with Autoruns, and see if you can find it in there. that should give you a path. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns

Comment: For whoever may land here, in my specific case, `Program` was a bookmark for a program that I had just uninstalled (a webmail service that was among the startup apps - not a MS product). I guess uninstalling it left behind the empty folder. I proved that by re-installing the webmail app: the `Program` now had a product name.

Comment: Bottom line: **Not malware!**

Comment: @JAP you should use answering feature if you managed to find a solution.